# Pentagon Geometry

Tags: geometry, area, polygons, geometric-construction

[image]

> $ABCDG$ is a pentagon, such that $\overline{AB} \parallel \overline{GD}$ and $\overline{AB}=2\overline{GD}$. Also, $\overline{AG} \parallel \overline{BC}$ and $\overline{AG}=3\overline{BC}$.
>
> We need to find ratio of areas of $\triangle BEC$ and $\triangle DFG$.

Using vector algebra, I was somehow able to calculate the ratio. My calculation suggests that the ratio is $\dfrac{6}{21}$. I am not sure of this though.

How do we find this ratio without resorting to the use of vector algebra? I am not able to figure out the suitable construction required to solve this problem.

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: You have two points named $E$ in your figure. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Arthur Oops..editing in a sec

Comment: I dont know the answer (by now) but seems funny to search it.

Comment: @Masacroso Why funny?

Comment: @Pkwssis Language? Probably means "entertaining", "amusing" something like that. I'll be bringing it home on the train for amusement too!

Comment: @Paul Such problems are often asked in various national and international mathematics Olympiads, where use of vector algebra, calculus etc is not acceptable..

Comment: A GeoGebra construction shows that the 6/21 ratio is true and is invariant under deformation of the parallelogram making up the construction.

Comment: @Paul this is true because all trasformations which maintain the parallelism are affinities, which in turn preserve ratios of areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $H$ complete parallelogram $\square ABHG$. Also, let $J$ and $K$ complete "double-size" parallelogram $\square ABKJ$ as shown; note that diagonal $BJ$ contains segment $BE$.

Since $GD\parallel AB$, we have $\triangle GDF \sim BAF$. (Why?) Since $|GD|= \frac12|AB|$, we have $|DF| = \frac12|FA| = \frac13|DA|$; thus, the area of $\triangle GDF$ (with "base" $DF$) is one-third the area of $\triangle GDA$ (with "base" $DA$). Moreover, four copies of $\triangle GDA$ fill $\square ABHG$. (Why?) Thus:
$$|\triangle GDF| = \frac13|\triangle GDA|=\frac13\cdot\frac14|\square ABHG|$$

Likewise, since $BC\parallel AJ$ and $|BC| = \frac16|AJ|$, and since *six* copies of $\triangle BCA$ fill $\square ABHG$, we have
$$|\triangle BCE| = \frac1{6+1}|\triangle BCA| = \frac17\cdot\frac16|\square ABHG|$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{|\triangle BCE|}{|\triangle GDF|} = \frac{1/42}{1/12} = \frac{12}{42} = \frac{6}{21} = \frac{2}{7}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you accept without proof that the given data determine this ratio uniquely we can set up the figure in such a way that the areas of the two triangles can be calculated easily.

Choose $$A=(0,0), \quad B=(2,0),\quad C=(2,1),\quad D=(1,3),\quad G=(0,3)\ .$$
Intersecting the  diagonals using analytic geometry then gives
$$E=\left({12\over7},{6\over7}\right), \quad F=\left({2\over3},2\right)\ .$$
The areas of the two triangles can now immediately be read off:
$$|\triangle(BEC)|={1\over2}\cdot 1\cdot{2\over7}={1\over7},\quad |\triangle(DFG)|={1\over2}\cdot 1\cdot1={1\over2}\ .$$
The required ratio therefore comes to ${\displaystyle{2\over7}}$, as you have found out yourself using vector algebra.

Comment: Isn't there a more general way to prove this?

Comment: This is indeed general - the sketch of the picture is in my answer. The generality comes from properties of affine transformations.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, any affine transformation preserves the ratio of distances and areas. If so, you can re-set your problem in an easy configuration, where $GD=BC=1$ and $AB\perp AG$, as in the picture below (sorry for the messy sketch).
You need to find the areas of the two triangles in this setting, which I guess is easier. Then all you need is an affinity to get the "simple" pentagon to the general one of your choice.

[image: upright pentagon]

Comment: Examples of Affine transformations, according to wikipedia, are  translation, scaling, homothety, similarity transformation, reflection, rotation, shear mapping, and compositions. An affine transformation does not give us the liberty to set $GD=BC=1$ or $AB \perp AG$, does it?

Comment: But of-course, from the language of the question, we can deduce that the ratio we require is independent of these features.

Comment: suppose your pentagon has $AB=h$ and $AG=k$, and the angle $BAG$ between them is $\theta$. Take the vectors $u_1=(2,0)$ and $u_2=(0,3)$ and the map $F$ such that $F(u_1)=(h,0)$ and $F(u_2)=(k\cos(\theta),k\sin(\theta))$. This is the affine transformation you want.

Comment: I did that..and arrived at the answer stated in the question.. I was searching for a geometrical approach, that involves geometrical construction

Comment: What do you mean by "geometrical construction" or "geometrical approach"?

Comment: Constructing this in GeoGebra I get the ratio to be 6/21 too, and is independent of the parallelogram to construct it.

Answer (score 0):

Several observations:

- $AG$ is parallel to $BC$.
- $AB$ is parallel to $DG$.

This means that extending $BC$ and $DG$ gives us a rectangle $AGXB$. (We let $X$ be the point where $BC$ and $DG$ meet, when sufficiently extended.) This is the key observation.

This tells us that the line $BG$ bisects the rectangle into equal-area triangles. The bottom triangle is $BXG$.

It follows from the square-extension that the line $DG$ has length half of the line $XG$.

Consequently, the line $BD$ bisects $BXG$ into two equal-area triangles: $BDG$ and $BDX$.

There is an unmarked point on the line $AC$ that intersects $BG$. We call that point $Y$. Note that because of the bisection, the area of $BEC$ is just half of the area of $BYC$.

Now we ask what the ratio between triangles $BYC$ and $DFG$ is. Then we will just divide that by two to find the desired result.

I'm currently not in a position to complete this answer -- the way to do it is to work out the areas of triangles $ABC$ and $ADG$, and from those find $BYC$ and $DFG$ by subtracting $AYB$ and $AFG$. Some use of the Pythagorean Theorem or Trigonometric rules may be necessary.

I'll complete this within 48 hours from now. (Or if someone wants to jump in and edit, please do so.)

Comment: $AGXB$ need not be a rectangle, only a parallelogram.

Comment: While the picture looks like there are right angles, that is not an assumption of the problem.